# display command unable to open x server error

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, display

I am running debian v10.0 on a raspberry pi. I have a directory of pictures with jpg, png and jpeg extensions. When I try to use `display image.extension` on any of them I get the error

```
display-im6.q16: unable to open x server @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/433
```

`display --verion` returns

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16
```

If I run `startx` into the GUI, I can right-click and open the images in both imageViewer and imageMagick.

How do I use `display` to view these images while in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You must be running an "X windows server" for `display` to be able to display. That's why it works after `startx`.

Comment: thank you. I noticed I could use `display` only while using a terminal in the GUI. I'm still learning my way around linux so I did not realize it would not work strictly via the commandline. Someone else recommended installing `fbi` which I tried out and it worked wonderfully. Thanks again.